# the form of the rejection region ( asymptotic )

Tags: hypothesis-testing, rejection-sampling

We consider $ z1,z2,...zn $  a series of iid random variable with average of $ m $ and variance $ \sigma ^ 2 $ . We want to test the hypothesis $ m \leq m_0 $against $ m $ > $ m_0$ with a risk threshold $ \alpha $ . How could I find  the form of the rejection region ( asymptotic )?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Central Limit Theorem, the asymptotic form of the rejection region will be:

$$ (m_0 + \left|\Phi^{-1}\left(\alpha\right)\right|\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}},\infty)$$

Where $n$ is your sample size.

Your test statistic will be the sample mean.

Comment: Thanks, but how can we calculate Phi for ($\alpha=0.05$) for example ?

Comment: @KenedYassine do you know what $\Phi$ is?

Comment: @KenedYassine actually, I had a typo...it's the inverse of the normal CDF (i.e., the $\alpha/2$ percentile)...sorry for any confusion.

Comment: I have another question If $ Y_1 ,Y_2.., Y_N $  iid of variance $  \sigma_Y^2 $ . by the TCL, if $ n $ is large :

$ \displaystyle P ( \sqrt{n} \vert \overline { Y} _n - m \vert\ge 1.96 \sigma_Y ) \simeq $ 0.05

What's the shape of the confidence interval (symetric) of $m$ with confidence 95%

$ \displaystyle P (m \in I) = 0.95 . $

Comment: I want to find the form of I

Comment: Why is the rejection region a _finite_ interval (implying a two-sided test) whereas it seems to make a lot more sense to reject the null when the sample mean is large. Also, the _center_ of your interval is the _unknown_ mean $m$.  -1 pending explanations and corrections.

Comment: @DilipSarwate you're quite right...how careless of me. I've revised the rejection region...it is indeed unbounded from above.

Comment: @DilipSarwate the interval is based on $m$ since that is the null hypothesis, this is not a confidence interval.

Comment: "the interval is based on m since that is the null hypothesis"   Errr...   no...   $m$ is an unknown parameter and we wish to determine if the null hypothesis -- that this _unknown_ $m$ is no larger than a _given_ number $m_0$ -- should be rejected. It makes no sense whatsoever to compare the sample mean to a threshold which depends on the _unknown_ $m$. How can we even figure out _what_ the threshold value is without knowing $m$? So, please continue in your efforts to fix your answer.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I miswrote...I took $m$ to be the null hypothesis. Completely glossed over the $m_0$

Comment: OK, I am removing my downvote.